# pytorch KLDivLoss loss is negative

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, pytorch, loss-function

my target is training a span prediction model

which can predict the position in the BERT output sequence

my input's shape is (batch_size, max_sequence_len(512),embedding_size(768))

output's shape will be (batch_size , max_sequence_len , 1) and the third dim is stand for kind a probability , then I will reshape output to (batch_size,max_sequence_len)

my label's shape is (batch_size , max_sequence_len), and in the max_sequence_len(512), only one position will be 1 and the others will be zero

and I've already check this

```
(batch_size is 2)
start_pos_labels.sum(dim=1)
output >> 
tensor([1.0000, 1.0000], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64)

start_pred.sum(dim=1)
tensor([1., 1.], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
```

but when I use nn.KLDivLoss() , output still be negative, I really dont know why

can somebody help me? thanks!

Here is my code
Model Code

```
class posClassfication_new(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(posClassfication_new, self).__init__()
        self.start_task = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(768, 1),
#             nn.ReLU(),
#             nn.Linear(256, 128),
#             nn.ReLU(),
#             nn.Linear(128, 1)
        )    
        self.end_task = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(768, 1),
#             nn.ReLU(),
#             nn.Linear(256, 128),
#             nn.ReLU(),
#             nn.Linear(128, 1)
        ) 
#             
    def forward(self, start_x,end_x):
        start_x = start_x.double()
        end_x = end_x.double()
        
        start_out = self.start_task(start_x)
        end_out = self.end_task(end_x)
        
        return start_out,end_out
```

training code

```
BATCH_SIZE = 8
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print("device:", device)

class PosTrainDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x, start_y,end_y):
        self.x = x
        self.start_y = start_y
        self.end_y = end_y

    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        x = self.x[idx]
        start_y = self.start_y[idx]
        end_y = self.end_y[idx]
        return x, start_y, end_y
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)
    
trainset = PosTrainDataset(pos_train_x , start_pos_labels_train , end_pos_labels_train)
trainloader = DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

pos_model = posClassfication_new()
pos_model = pos_model.to(device)
pos_model = pos_model.double()
pos_model.train()

pos_loss = nn.KLDivLoss()
# pos_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(pos_model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)

EPOCHS = 5
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    running_loss = 0.0
    for data in trainloader:
        x, start_pos_labels, end_pos_labels = [t.to(device) for t in data]
        mini_batch = x.size()[0]
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        
        start_pred , end_pred = pos_model(x,x)
        
        start_pred = start_pred.reshape((mini_batch,512))
        end_pred = end_pred.reshape((mini_batch,512))


        start_pred = torch.nn.functional.softmax(start_pred,dim=1)
        end_pred = torch.nn.functional.softmax(end_pred,dim=1)
        
        start_pos_labels = start_pos_labels + 0.0001
        start_pos_labels = torch.nn.functional.softmax(start_pos_labels,dim=1)
        
        end_pos_labels = end_pos_labels  + 0.0001
        end_pos_labels = torch.nn.functional.softmax(end_pos_labels,dim=1)
        
#         start_pos_labels = torch.argmax(start_pos_labels,dim=1)
#         end_pos_labels = torch.argmax(end_pos_labels,dim=1)

        start_loss = pos_loss(start_pred,start_pos_labels)
        end_loss = pos_loss(end_pred,end_pos_labels)
        
        
        loss = start_loss + end_loss
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
        
    torch.save(pos_model,'pos_model_single_task.pkl')
    print('[epoch %d] loss: %.3f' %(epoch + 1, running_loss))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`nn.KLDivLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.KLDivLoss) expects the input to be log-probabilties.

From the documentation:

> As with [`NLLLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.NLLLoss), the input given is expected to contain *log-probabilities* and is not restricted to a 2D Tensor. The targets are given as *probabilities* (i.e. without taking the logarithm).

You can apply [`nn.functional.log_softmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.log_softmax) to your predictions to get log-probabilities.

```py
start_pred = torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(start_pred,dim=1)
end_pred = torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(end_pred,dim=1)
```