# Why KL divergence is negative in Pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I'm trying to get the KL divergence between 2 distributions using Pytorch, but the output is often negative which [shouldn't be the case](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/335197/why-kl-divergence-is-non-negative):

```py
import torch 
import torch.nn.functional as F

x_axis_kl_div_values = []
for epoch in range(200):
    # each epoch generates 2 different distributions
    input_1 = torch.empty(10).normal_(mean=torch.randint(1,50,(1,)).item(),std=0.5).unsqueeze(0)
    input_2 = torch.empty(10).normal_(mean=torch.randint(1,50,(1,)).item(),std=0.5).unsqueeze(0)

    kl_divergence = F.kl_div(input_1.log(), input_2, reduction='batchmean')
    x_axis_kl_div_values.append(kl_divergence.item())

x_axis_kl_div_values 
>>> 
[324.4713134765625,
 -69.10758972167969,
 -92.42606353759766,
```

From the Pytorch forum I found [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/kl-divergence-produces-negative-values/16791/1) that mentions that their issue was that the inputs were not proper distributions, which is not the case in my code as I'm creating a normal distribution. From [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806681/pytorch-kldivloss-loss-is-negative) it seems like their issue was that the `nn.KLDivLoss` expects the input to be log-probabiltie, but again, I did that in my code. So I'm not sure what I'm missing

Comment: As the answer below (and the comments in the linked threads) imply, you do not seem to apply the corresponding concepts correctly; `input_1` and `input_2` should be probability distributions themselves, not samples drawn from them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it stems from a misunderstanding of the underlying mathematical & statistical concepts, hence it is not actually about programming as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`normal_` fills with values drawn from a normal distribution, but that doesn't mean that the resulting tensor represents a normal or even a valid probability distribution.

E.g. `[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]` is an valid uniform distribution. If you had used `torch.empty(10).uniform_()`, you would not get a tensor that represents a uniform distribution. Each value in the tensor represents the probability of that index occurring.

In your code, you could make the probabilities sum to 100%:

`F.kl_div( (input_1/input_1.sum() ).log(), input_2 / input_2.sum(), reduction='batchmean')`

which would give a positive result.